# A simple way to add alternating lines of .txt file to a wx.ListCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I wondered if there was a simple way to add data from a text file to a wxPython `wx.ListCtrl` and set it so that alternating lines go to three separate columns. So for example, lines 1, 4, 7, and 10 would be added to column 1 and lines 2, 5, 8, and 11 would be added to column 2 and lines 3, 6, 9, and 12 would be added to column 3...so on, so forth. I've opened the .txt file using              `with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:` 
and then used `f.readlines()[1]` to read the first line and set it to let's say the variable `a`, and then manually added variable `a` to the list, but I thought there must be a more efficient way to do it.

Or, in retrospect, is there another way I should write the data to the .txt file? Right now I'm writing three items to the file when the user clicks the submit button. These are the items that should be displayed in the three columns. Right now each one goes on a separate line in the text file, but maybe I should simply separate them with commas or something?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get every third item in a list, you can do myList[::3].

For example,

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = []
>>> for i in xrange(1,22):
...     a.append(i)
...
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
>>> b = a       # start index of b will be the first item
>>> b = b[::3]
>>> b
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]
>>> c = a[1:]   # start index of c will be the second item
>>> c = c[::3]
>>> c
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20]
>>> d = a[2:]   # start index of d will be the third item
>>> d = d[::3]
>>> d
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
```

So you could split your readlines() list into 3 separate list like this, then add them to your ListCtrl.

Readlines just returns a list, where each item in the list is a line from your file.  So if you have the file open as f, it would look like this,

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
list1 = lines
list1 = list1[::3]
list2 = lines[1:]
list2 = list2[::3]
list3 = lines[2:]
list3 = list3[::3]
```

Now `list1` holds every third line (0,3,6,9), `list2` holds (1,4,7,10), and `list3` holds (2,5,8,11).

Comment: Ah, so what exactly do I reference in the `readlines()` function? I tried using the a list, and then using the `b=b[::3]`, and then using b in `readlines(b)`, but it gave me a type error.

Comment: Wait, I reread it and realized what you meant. Awesome, works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Readlines just returns a list, where each item in the list is a line from your file.  I edited my original post with new code.